# Java valid declarations of a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was going through one App which is suggested for the OCJP exam. I found one question about the two-dimensional array.

**Question:** Valid declarations of a two-dimensional array.

**Options:**

1. `int[][] array2D;`
2. `int[2][2] array2D;`
3. `int array2D[];`
4. `int[] array2D[];`
5. `int[][] array2D[];`

**My selection:** `int[][] array2D;` and `int[] array2D[]` but when I submit my answer it tells me that `int[] array2D[]` is wrong and correct is `int[][] array2D[];`

I think the `int[][] array2D[];` is incorrect answer.

1. Am I right?
2. Is `int[] array2D[]` recommended in programming?

Comment: Your question was so poorly formatted, please do some effort next time.

Comment: 1) You are correct. 2) `int[] array2D[]` is discouraged by the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) itself: *We do not recommend "mixed notation" in array variable declarations, where bracket pairs appear on both the type and in declarators; nor in method declarations, where bracket pairs appear both before and after the formal parameter list.*

Comment: how the hell 5th option is correct ?

Comment: 3th Option is not even 2D array. It can have only one set.

Comment: @Sikorski you are right, it's not correct by java specification but when I write `int[][] array2D[];` JVM doesn't give any error not even compile time or runtime.

Comment: JVM wouldn't give you error for this, JVM doesn't know you want it to be treated as 2d array.

Comment: @RC. Sry to making your effort to format my question. I tried putting ` char but instead of that it went ' , Will take care of it next time.

Comment: @VimalPanchal No worries, you can use the `{}` button in the toolbar for code

Comment: @RC Is it possible for you to revert - 2 vote? I want to ask another question about hashing collision but not able to do that.

Comment: @VimalPanchal I didn't vote on your question, so I cannot revert anything but I can +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this seems to be both options 1 and 4.

```
int[][] array2D
```

is a standard way to declare a 2-d int array.

Although  `int[] array2D[];` it is not a good practice it will work and will be a valid declaration.

Comment: typo in last statement ? int [] array2D [] perhaps ?

Comment: *"not a good practice"* is called *"we do not recommend"* in the JLS. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130095/java-valid-declarations-of-a-two-dimensional-array#comment71427286_42130095).

Comment: @Akshay agreed with your answer.